# Spring kundera cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, kundera

Is it possibility to populate database after auto creating with Kundera?
I have prepared import.cql file with required data for application and need something like

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="import.sql"/>
```

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to manually run these scripts to create application data. Only [Schema Generation using Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Schema-Generation) is possible.

Comment: Indeed. However it is not usable way for update DB in SAAS solutions, f.e. fill static data as like countries/cities/states etc and update them. In my opinion Kundera require tool for support migrations for altering tables, executing custom scripts. @Flyway great tool but I'm not sure about Cassandra support

Comment: Thanks @NikedLab We(_Kundera Team_) can think about adding this feature.

Comment: It will be great. Thanks